# can't access database record from controller in rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I can get a database record from `rails console` but can't find the record from controller. They both use the same syntax, such as `User.all`. I debug through `inspect`,return `nil`. I want to know the next step how to debug it? Give me some hints,thanks~

Comment: Is your Rails environment different for the server and the console? You can test this by printing out `Rails.env` in both the controller and `rails console`.

Comment: I just tried show the same environment "development"

Comment: If you do User.count in the rails console and User.count on your breakpoint in the controller does it show the same amount ?

Comment: Try restarting your rails server

Comment: @Typpex  I tried as you say. Yes it show the same count and at same time I haven't set anything but it just goes well.

Comment: Thank you all ! The problem was solved. How to close this question?

Comment: @lazybios if you dont plan to provide the found answer below, just delete the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too embarrassing I saved it just by restart server `rails s`. I have be taught when you encounter any  error,you'd better to find error log. If there is no any log info. Maybe you should consider whether your program have logic error. When you exclude the logic error. It's time to restart you program or service. Of course, When you project is online service.you should act with caution! So you know this tips is only for newbies like me.I still have a lot to say,but my English is too bad.Hope for can help passersby who have same problem with me.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for not just commenting, my reputation was not high enough. I'm a newbie as well.

I'd suggest that you post the answer also.

When I've had issues with being able to get something in the console and not the controller, it's usually been a permissions issue.  Strong Parameters to be exact.

Since you don't provide a code example, I'll leave one here.

```
private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :postname).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
  end
```

Something like this usually fixes the issue ... in my case, I usually have forgotten to add what I wanted into the permitted area.

Hope this helps for the future.